# Swiffy vs Flash CS6 HTML5 Export for custom fonts and standard bitmaps animations

Tags: flash, html, google-swiffy, createjs, flash-cs6

Is it better to use the built-in CreateJS HTML5 exporter in Flash CS6 or Swiffy, for simple animations involving bitmaps and custom fonts

Answer (score 3):

We had tried both options in our site. We suggest to use createJS, as the output generated is readable. But it will not support the complex action script and swfs.

Answer (score 0):

In comparing swiffy and createjs outputs we noticed that somehow the swiffy canvas is resolution independent, when it comes to drawing vectors. This means that by default the output is retina compatible.

We make a lot of banners and most of our clients will review the work on a retina laptop or ipad at some point. So createjs was a no-go for us. You have to jump through some hoops to make the createjs output from flash retina ready.

We had very low expectations for swiffy when we started testing it, but honestly it has really impressed us with how closely it matches swf output. Complex masking, blend modes, font conversion, vector, etc. Things that are very hard or impossible with hand coded html are no problem. I'm not sure how swiffy renders the canvas like this, but it is pretty awesome and I wish createjs did the same.

Comment: Swiffy just recreates the flash functionality. The content in CreateJS IS resolution independent, but it requires you to tell it what size it is. This is something you have to set up manually. For example, the `exportRoot` generated by Flash CC can easily be scaled -- you would just have to listen for resize, adjust the canvas, and set the scale of the exportRoot to fill the space. CreateJS with Flash is not meant to be a "conversion" framework, but rather a way to work with Flash-created assets, and definitely requires a little more understanding of the code, and work on the developer's part.